# Как переопределить нажатие на иконку меню в ActionBar?

Tags: android, actionbar

У меня есть ActionBar  из библиотеки `android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;`
Я хочу  просто установить свою иконку на кнопку меню и при нажатии на нее выполнить действия. Иконку я смог установить вот так:

```
<style name="AppThemeOverflow" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/OverFlow</item>
    </style>

    <style name="OverFlow" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton.Overflow">
        <item name="android:src">@drawable/ic_white_ask_question</item>
    </style>
```

и применил этот стиль к активити. Выглядит это так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но при нажатии на меню я вижу это:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и это правильно, так и должно работать меню. НО!!! мне нужно сразу выполнить действие которое выполняется на нажатие елемента меню сразу при нажатии на само меню. Тоесть я нехочу чтобы появлялись элементы меню а сразу чтото происходило. Может тут не меню нужно но я не знаю. Имортирую с шерлока, там уже было реализовано без лишних костылей.

**РЕДАКИРУЮ**

Вот мое меню

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
            android:id="@+id/menu_subscription_help"
            android:showAsAction="always"
            android:title="@string/WhatIsSubscription"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_white_ask_question"/>
</menu>
```

если убрать все стили и оставить так как есть, то иконка просто три вертикальные точки и так же открывается меню при нажатии на нее

Вот код

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.menu_subscription_help:
                WebHelpManager.GetHelpSubscription(SubscriptionListActivity.this);
                break;
            case android.R.id.home: {
                finish();
                return true;
            }
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Все ответы были близки но не точные. Помог этот: [решение](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26890555/4781349)

Answer (score 3):

Лучше используйте Toolbar. В нём вы сможете всё что угодно кастомизировать, кнопки какие вам захочется вставить и т.д.

Если хотите использовать всё же ActionBar, просто обрабатывайте нажатия на кнопки меню в методе:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

где id - id пункта меню, который вы в XML прописываете. Вы ведь меню через XML создаёте? Это не совсем понятно из вопроса. Иконку там же, в XML, можно менять, не вижу здесь особого смысла в использовании стилей.

UPD: просто создайте такое меню с одним пунктом:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_add_size"
        android:title="@string/menu_add_item"
        android:orderInCategory="10"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add" />
</menu>
```

А в onOptionsItemSelected задавайте поведение по нажатию на пункт с id == menu_add_size. Не вижу проблемы.

Comment: Вы написали очевидные вещи. Естественно я знаю как обработать нажатия на элементы меню. Перечитайте еще раз вопрос. Мне нужно наоборот не открывать список с элементами меню(в моем случае этот список всего из одного элемента) а выполнить то что выполниться при нажатии на элемент, при нажатии на само меню. Другими словами я тыкаю на меню и у меня не открывается оно а сразу выполняются действия

Comment: @ip696 сделал апдейт ответа. При таком сценарии меню и не должно появляться, поэтому я не понял, с чем у вас связаны затруднения.

Comment: я тоже апдейтил вопрос гляньте пожалуйста

Answer (score 1):

Отловить нажатие на кнопку меню можно, как вариант, переопределив метод `onPrepareOptionsMenu()`

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    //делаем то что трубуется
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Вызывается он как раз при нажатии на кнопку меню, но так же и сразу же после создания `Activity`.

Ну а вообще для этой цели подойдет просто элемент меню, для которого:

```
android:showAsAction="always"
```

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, вы не сможете переопределить именно эту иконку меню так, как вы хотите, так как она собирает в себе те пункты меню, которые не входят в текущий размер бара или помечены, как `showAsAction=" never"`.
Вам нужно оставить overflow-иконку в покое и добавить свою, с атрибутом `showAsAction="always"`, тогда она появится рядом с этой иконкой и будет реагировать, как вам надо.

PS: Шерлок сам как бы костыль, там может быть реализовано все, что угодно и не обязательно аналогичное присутствует в оригинальном `ActionBar`

**UPD**

overflow-иконка относится к системной функциональности, скрывать ее не надо, так как это нарушит работу системы. С другой стороны, она не должна появляться, если все иконки входят в размер бара и нет скрытых пунктов ( с атрибутом `showAsAction=" never"`). Так же она появляется, если нет физической кнопки меню.
В общем то все верно указано в [этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/449389/177345).
Можете дополнительно почитать про иконки в ActionBar [здесь](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/177-urok-107-android-3-actionbar-razmeschenie-elementov.html)

Comment: Видимо это то что мне нужно, так как я видел этот атрибут в старом коде. Могли бы пример показать или подробдней как это сделать? и мне тогда скрыть как то надо вторую иконку?

Comment: Да мне достался проект старый. Я его привожу в чувства. Но нужно весь дизайн оставить как был, потому и парюсь

Comment: showAsAction="always" не рекомендуется использовать. showAsAction="ifRoom" будет работать также, но в случае резкого увеличения количества пунктов меню - всё отобразится без косяков.